# Is it correct to attach the superlative suffix to substantives? Like "in gambissima"?

Tags: word-meaning

I heard a few times the use of the suffix *-issimo/issima* with substantives and couldn't find an immediate appropriate translation, so I thought it must be metaphorical way of speaking. I don't remember many examples, but recently I stumbled upon the *in gambissima* expression. Is it grammatically correct to attach the suffix to substantives in some cases? Are there any other examples of this practice?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I informal speech you can even say *in gambissimissima*, but in more formal contexts avoid it.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Yes, ... if you are 6 years old. Older than that using `issimissima` sounds *really* awkward. If you want to sound "funny" you could also say *in gamberrima* which will have exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past we had *il campionissimo*, that is, Fausto Coppi. He was so good in cycling that calling him *campione* was too reductive. Probably the term was coined under the influence of *il generalissimo Franco* (taken from Spanish, of course).

Such a usage of the superlative with nouns rather than adjectives has its roots in sport journalism, where people is often in search for astonishing words.

The phrase *in gambissima* is a joke for saying that someone is *in gamba*, that is, in good health (or, by extension, good in something) at a very high grade. So it is the superlative of an an adverb, which is not so uncommon, actually, for instance *benissimo* and *malissimo*.

Thus *sta benissimo* can become *è in gambissima*.

Comment: So it's correct to use "il campionissimo" and such astonishing words?

Comment: @symbiotech Yes, it is. Abuse is dangerous, of course.

Comment: @symbiotech: In linguistic matters, it is dubious what “is this correct” means. Grammars and dictionaries register actual use, when it has spread among a population of speakers of a languages. You might say that the whole Italian Vulgar is a very incorrect Latin (with declensions and conjugations all amiss), or you might say - as one usually does - that it is an entirely new linguistic phenomenon. On a different scale, the same holds for single constructions, words and suffixes like your “-issimo”. So: what do you mean by “correct”?